# Universal path function for all small trees

Tags: graph-theory

Let $f$ be a function $f: [k]^2 \rightarrow [k]$ (Where $[k]$ is the set $
\{0,1,\dots,k-1\}$).

A function $f$ is called **$n$-universal path function** if for every tree $T$ with $n$ vertices there exists an injective function $h: T \rightarrow [k]$ such that:

$(*)$ For every two vertices $x,y \in T$, the sequence:
$a_0 = h(x), a_n=f(a_{n-1},h(y))$ is contained in $h[T]$ and converges to $h(y)$.

What is the minimal $k$ for which it is possible to find an $n$-universal path function $f$?

I will appreciate any hints or ideas about this.

### Previous attempts

Bounding from below: There could be at most $k^n$ different $h$ functions, and there could be $n^{n-2}$ different labeled trees (Cayley's formula). As every tree should get a different $h$ function, we conclude that $k^n \geq n^{n-2}$ and so $\log(k) \geq \frac{(n-2)}{n}\log(n)$, so $k \geq n{2^{(n-2)/n}} \approx n$

Bounding from the other side, for $k = n\cdot n^{n-2} = n^{n-1} $ one could create a function $f$ that "includes all the small trees" and thus is $n$-universal path function.